# Backyard Tournament Brackets

Tags: combinatorics

Every Labor Day Weekdend my family has a reunion where we play a very organized backyard games tournament. I have been in charge of brackets for 10 years and have yet to have a smooth day. Round Robin Tournament generators can give me perfect match ups, but doesn't take into account we are playing different games.  Ideally, I'd like every team to not repeat any of the games or play a team twice. We play in pairs. The number of games doesn't matter. Game number can be manipulated to make the brackets work.

There won't be any elimination, the point of the day is to have fun and catch up with people as you're playing games. I'd like to play simultaneously too if possible.

Trouble is, year to year we don't know how many teams are coming. So I'd like to have master brackets with numbers for the teams and letters for games that can just be plugged in. I'd need master brackets for anywhere from 8 teams to 18 teams. With 12-18 being the most likely range for number of teams. (If there's an odd number of teams there would just be a bye)

I know there has to be a mathematical way to do this, but it's beyond me.

Thank you for any assistance!

I'd be willing to change things too if a solution would make the day run better.

Edit for clarification:
I've been working at this problem for 10 years. I've tried just winging the brackets, I've tried 100% using an online generator, I've tried using an online generator for match ups and then working out the games myself by picking games out of a hat. I've tried using an online generator and then manually manipulating the matches to eliminate playing the same games twice. Nothing works. I've heard of Latin Squares, but I can't make heads or tails of them for this application.

Comment: Are you sure there's no limit to the number of games, or how many matchups each game has? If it's possible for there to be 1,000 different games, say, you could easily make sure no team plays the same game twice, reducing the problem to keeping the matchups distinct.

Comment: No realistic limit to the number of games. From what I could remember we've played about 10-12 unique games over the past decade.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the round-robin brackets themselves, labour-saving resources exist on the web, such as [this one](https://www.printyourbrackets.com/roundrobin.html). I recommend having them all at the ready.

If you are willing to have ready as many distinct games as there are teams, here's a handy method that will ensure that nobody plays the same game twice. I'll assume there are 20 different games (just for this example—the method works as long as the number of games is at least as large as the number of teams), numbered 1 to 20.

To decide which game the matchup of team $A$ vs. team $B$ plays: calculate $A+B$.

- If $A+B\le20$, then that's the number of the game they play against each other.
- If $A+B>20$, then subtract $20$ from it; then that ($A+B-20$) is the number of the game they play against each other.

For example, when team $6$ plays team $8$, they play game $6+8=14$. When team $17$ plays team $9$, they play game $17+9-20=6$.